# Upgrade to Sonar 3.1 requires to uninstall many (all) plugins

Tags: sonarqube

I would like to upgrade my current sonar installation from 3.0.1 to 3.1 (or higher). As usual, the system checks the compatibility of the installed plugins with the new release. While normally, this is not much an issue, sonar now wants me to remove seven plugins, I rely on. Steps to perform sonar system upgrade (sorry, I can't post a picture):

> Sonar 3.1
>
> Date: Jun 13, 2012
>
> Release Notes: Global dashboards, Findbugs 2.0, rules for unit tests
>
> How to upgrade: Follow those steps to upgrade Sonar from version 3.0.1 to version 3.1 :
>
> the plugin Findbugs which is not compatible with Sonar 3.1.
>
> the plugin Surefire which is not compatible with Sonar 3.1.
>
> the plugin Checkstyle which is not compatible with Sonar 3.1.
>
> the plugin PMD which is not compatible with Sonar 3.1.
>
> the plugin JaCoCo which is not compatible with Sonar 3.1.
>
> the plugin Cobertura which is not compatible with Sonar 3.1.
>
> the plugin Squid for Java which is not compatible with Sonar 3.1.
>
> Stop Sonar
>
> Download and install Sonar 3.1 after having carefully read the upgrade guide.
>
> Start Sonar

While I can understand that I would have to uninstall Findbugs as sonar 3.1 switches to Findbugs 2.0, I hardly can imagine that all the other plugins are incompatible with the new sonar minor release. Of course, there are no pending plugin updates.

So, is this normal or is there somewhere an error in the system? What can I do about it?

Comment: Have you gotten any ground with this?I have the EXACT same thing going on with the Sonar instance I manage as well.  I had a plugin that it said needed updating, updated it, and now I have the same plugins that it's claiming are incompatible. I am on sonar 3.1 as well.

The only thing I can imagine is because they are system plugins, they will be replaced with the upgrade?

Comment: I finally resolved the problem with the help on the official mailing list: http://sonar.15.x6.nabble.com/Upgrading-Sonar-3-0-1-gt-3-1-requires-to-uninstall-almost-all-plugins-td5014227.html The bottom line is, you can safely ignore the warnings and upgrade to 3.5.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warnings can be safely ignored when upgrading to 3.5.1: http://sonar.15.x6.nabble.com/Upgrading-Sonar-3-0-1-gt-3-1-requires-to-uninstall-almost-all-plugins-td5014227.html